# Event on button on InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Got this click event on a button inside the infoMap on google maps

```
<button @click="showInfoDevice" class="deviceBtn">{{ $t("device.showDeviceInfo") }} </button>
```

with the method just returning a console log for testing

```
showInfoDevice(): void {console.log("Clicked");}
```

But the method doesn't work and when I inspect the button, it does not have the event on it...
Does anyone know why this may be and how to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVSYf.png)
(It's in Vue)

Comment: is there anything happening in the browser console when you click the button? or any error when you load the page? (I take you're using typescript)

Comment: I think the issue is that it's added to the InfoWindow in Google Map and that's not customizable, so will have to solve it some other way